# How can I individually retry fork joined Observable by clicking button

Tags: angular, rxjs

Suppose I have 1 highest Observable that flatMap to Observable.forkJoin.

The number of joined observables is depend on highest Observable.

Is there a way I can individually retry joined observables by clicking a button if any of them are fail and then resolve the highest Observable with complete set of data after all of failures are retried and success.

Comment: Can you show the code you have right now? The `forkJoin` emits just once and then completes so you can't simply retry individual source Observables. You can only create the `forkJoin` again.

Comment: I don't have any code yet.I'm still designing the flow but base on your comment I guess I must go with individual observers and another observer to observe them